# How to publish an Alpha Internal Track app version from AppCenter to PlayStore

Tags: google-play-console, visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

I've sucessfully connected my app account with Console Developers Play Store and AppCenter

Inside Appcenter dashboard I have:

AppName => Distribute -> stores haves 3 ways to distribute app version

- Production
- Beta
- Alpha.

I've created into PlayStore an Alpha Internal Track... But it does not show in AppCenter... How can I publish from App Center to Play Store with a Private Internal Alpha Version

[image: Available Distribute options AppCenter]

[image: Internal Track Alpha Version inside PlayConsole]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was wondering the same and asked the question through Intercom. Here is Anvesh's answer:

> Hi there, thank you for contacting us!
>
> Right now, Google APIs don't expose a way to get to the Test/Customized tracks.
>   Our Team is having a close watch on those API changes so AppCenter can support them.
>
> Until the APIs themselves don't expose these, I'm afraid we're helpless.

Comment: Related issue on AppCenter's GitHub: [Google Play internal test track support #125](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/125)